# Redirection according to browser language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a simple app where the user can select the language to use in my app between English and Polish.

When the user opens my website, this is the behavior I want:

- If Browser Language = English then switch to the Polish language.
- If Browser Language = Polish then do nothing.
- Assume Polish is a default language.

Because it's a very simple app, I'm using jQuery for translation.

Below is my solution so far:

JSFIDDLE: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ds35wzb7/)

```js
//redirect
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  if (userLang == "pl-pl") {
    break;
  } else {
    userLang = "eng-gb"
  }
}
});



// translation

// The default language is Polish
var lang = "pl-pl";
// Check for localStorage support
if ('localStorage' in window) {

  var usrLang = localStorage.getItem('uiLang');
  if (usrLang) {
    lang = usrLang
  }
}


var arrLang = {
  "pl-pl": {
    "Valentine": "Do Walentynek zostało już tylko",
  },
  "en-gb": {
    "valentine": "Remaining days to Valentines!",
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
  });

  $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
  });

  // get/set the selected language
  $(".translate").click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr("id");

    // update localStorage key
    if ('localStorage' in window) {
      localStorage.setItem('uiLang', lang);
    }

    $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="translate">
  <ul class="language">
    <li class="eng translate" id="en-gb">EN</li>
    <li class="pl translate" id="pl-pl">PL</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="rss-feed">
  <p class="lang" key="valentine">Do Walentynek zostało już tylko
  </p>
  <span id="mybenfit-timer" class="lang" key="days">
       </span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, my solution is not working. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Check `userLang == "eng-gb"`: this line is a comparison (not an assignment). Also, the key in your object is `en-gb` not `eng`.

Comment: Hi jake , still not working ;(

Comment: @Cue can you please explain why my question is duplicate????  ur link its about language detection not redirecting :( be specific please why u think its duplicate ,

Answer (score 1):

- the `userLang` return `en-GB` so the language is two lowercase characters and the country two uppercase characters so the if statement should be `if(userLang == 'pl-PL')` not  `if(userLang == 'pl-pl')` it will always return false by your way
- BUT while you just need the language right?  you can try This .. and always use the language in two lowercase characters .. no need to use `pl-pl` or `en-GB` you can use `pl` or `en`

```js
//redirect
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  console.log(userLang);
  var userLang = userLang.split('-')[0];
  console.log(userLang);
  var userLang = (userLang !== "pl")? 'en' : 'pl';
  console.log(userLang);
  
  var arrLang = {
    "pl": {
      "Valentine": "Do Walentynek zostało już tylko",
    },
    "en": {
      "valentine": "Remaining days to Valentines!",
    }
  }
  console.log(arrLang[userLang].valentine);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi Mohamed, your method looks good, did you test your code?  I tried your method to check your method if it works but, unfortunately its not working, please let me know if your method works, thanks

Comment: @JeffersonXMasonic I wonder about your question .. I posted my answer with working snippet so what do you mean *its not working* .. you mean not working on your code??

Comment: I tested  your method in chrome by changing the language as the question specify but it just display in console `pl' while the browser language is English, that is why am asking if you tested your code and works,

Comment: Hi Mohamed , @JeffersonXMasonic is right your code does not work , I tested on chrome , firefox and edge , I would like to know if you tested this code and if it works on your side , thanks a lot for explanation and help,

Comment: yes @JeffersonXMasonic i tested it on Chrome 63.0.3239.132  .. Opera 56.0.3051.52 .. Firefox Quantum 61.0 and even in IE 11 .. the final result is the same in all this browsers even I changed the language .. the only different is the output of `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage` in Chrome and IE it output `en-GB` But in Opera and Firefox return just `en` but its not affect the final result of my code .. so don't worry about it

Comment: @user9964622 hi .. see my previous comment :)

Comment: @JeffersonXMasonic you need to check for just the language so change all `pl-pl` and `en-gb` and all of those in your script and work with the language `pl` or `en` even in `arrLang`  use `"pl" :` instead of `"pl-pl" :` and  `"en" :` instead of `"en-gb"` .. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following I hope it helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // translation

    // The default language is English
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    var lang = "pl-pl";

    // If Browser Language == English then switch to the Polish language.
    // since there en-GB en-US ...
    if(userLang.split('-')[0] == 'en'){ 
        lang = "pl-pl";
    }

    // Check for localStorage support
    if('localStorage' in window){

        var usrLang = localStorage.getItem('uiLang');
        if( typeof(usrLang) === 'string' && usrLang !== 'undefined') {
            lang = usrLang
        }

    }

    var arrLang = {
        "pl-pl": {
            "valentine": "Do Walentynek zostało już tylko",
            "days": " 10 dni"
        },
        "en-gb": {
            "valentine": "Remaining days to Valentines!",
            "days": " 10 days"
        }
    }


    $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
    });

    // get/set the selected language
    $(".translate").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var lang = $(this).attr("id");

        // update localStorage key
        if('localStorage' in window){
            localStorage.setItem('uiLang', lang);
        }

        $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
            $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would be surprised if not. The code should in any major browser out there that supports the jquery version you are going to use. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Property names are case sensitive.

Your property name for Polish in `arrLang` is different to that of English. `pl-pl` is `Valentine` while `en-gb` is `valentine`. But your `key="valentine"` looks for the latter in `pl-pl` which does not exist.

Lowercase them both et voila.

```
var arrLang = {
  "pl-pl": {
    "valentine": "Do Walentynek zostało już tylko",
  },
  "en-gb": {
    "valentine": "Remaining days to Valentines!",
  }
}
```